# C++ Get binary value of a buffer

Tags: c++, binary, buffer

I'm really sorry for the wording of the question, it's a bit confusing.

So lets say I have a buffer:

```
char buffer[4] = {0, 0, 2, 0};
```

if we convert it all to binary, we get one 32 bit unsigned int:

`00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000`

The value of it is 512.

So my question is, how do I get to the answer of 512 using c++? Preferably with some library function.

Thanks for any answer, and I'm very sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Do you realize that you're represented 512 as a big endian?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can perform some bitwise operations:

```
unsigned int converter(const char buffer[4]) {
  return (buffer[0] << 24) |
         (buffer[1] << 16) |
         (buffer[2] << 8) |
         (buffer[3]);
}
```

[Example Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eggVnA4n59GnEYi1)

Comment: The only correct answer! reinterpret_cast and unions are propagated in other answers, but they are not allowed (the way they are used) by the standard.

Comment: @AntonF. Please show us where unions aren't allowed, by specification, to be used for conversion from one type to another...

Comment: My comment at the other answer: 
It works on most compilers, but is not safe and not portable. See en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union section Member lifetime: "The lifetime of a union member begins when the member is made active. If another member was active previously, its lifetime ends." Think of optimization/register storage etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's only 512 if you're big endian. You're writing down the binary format as MSB : LSB but that's not how you're representing the bytes in the array buffer. The "LSB" in the array is buffer[0], the little endian representation is shown below.

A portable way of [type punning](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/959) is to actually use memcpy. It's actually all optimized away per this [compiler explorer comparison](https://godbolt.org/z/nVXagN), even the function call.

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <cstdint>                                                              
#include <array>                                                                
#include <cstring>                                                              

std::array<unsigned char, 4> buffer = {0, 2, 0, 0};                             

template <std::size_t N>                                                        
std::uint32_t char_buf_to_int( std::array<unsigned char, N>& b )                
{                                                                               
    std::uint32_t i;                                                            
    std::memcpy( &i, b.data(), b.size() );                                      
    return i;                                                                   
}                                                                               

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    std::cout << char_buf_to_int( buffer ) << std::endl;                        
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Comment: reinterpret_cast is not allowed this way. The standard forbids casting between unrelated pointer types! I had to learn this recently (I didn't believe it before).

Comment: @AntonF. static_cast works on related types, reinterpret cast works on unrelated types. A static cast on this example would fail at compile time,  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ . "reinterpret_cast converts any pointer type to any other pointer type, even of unrelated classes. The operation result is a simple binary copy of the value from one pointer to the other. All pointer conversions are allowed: neither the content pointed nor the pointer type itself is checked."

Comment: It works on most compilers (but sometimes not if optimization is involved). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast says: "Only the following conversions can be done with reinterpret_cast, except when such conversions would cast away constness or volatility. ..." The cast between unrelated pointer types (pointer to integrals) is not listed an is explicitly forbidden (same text as in the standard).

Comment: @Anton F: that's incorrect. You can cast between unrelated pointer types with reinterpret_cast<>. From the page you linked: `Any object pointer type T1* can be converted to another object pointer type cv T2*`

Comment: @ppetraki: cplusplus.com writes "The conversions that can be performed by reinterpret_cast but not by static_cast are low-level operations based on reinterpreting the binary representations of the types, which on most cases results in code which is system-specific, and thus non-portable." Non-portable operations are not allowed by the standard. This includes casting between unrelated pointer types. It works (no compiler errors), but it is not allowed. cppreference.com is nearer to the standard.

Comment: @PlinyTheElder: Primitives and arrays are not objects. Pointer to unrelated integral types cannot be converted this way.

Comment: @AntonF. If you keep reading, you'll find under **type aliasing** the following. _Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:_ ... **AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17)char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.**

That's an array of unsigned char. So I can do whatever I want.

Comment: @ppetraki: I don't know if int is an object. If so, you are basically right. But this is not portable. As you mentioned in your answer, big and little endian could happen. If you always store values with the same system you read it and never port the code, this will probably work.

Comment: @ppetraki No, you cannot. Your code is *Undefined behavior* and risky. You can "safely" reinterpret `T` to `char`, it's not true vice-versa. You cannot cast an array of char into an `unsigned int`. Architectural representation could be different (memory alignment).

Comment: You could copy back the object bytes stored in a char buffer to an object by using memcpy. Direct access is not allowed. And be sure that size of unsigned int ist 4 bytes, or use uint32_t. Use: unsigned char buffer[4] = {0, 2, 0, 0}; uint32_t Val = 0; memcpy( &Val, buffer, 4u ); std::cout << Val << std::endl; The Problem with big/little endian remains.

Comment: @ppetraki: You can convert pointers to other (unrelated) pointer types and back, but you cannot safely dereference the result, so your expression "*reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>( &buffer )" is not allowed by the standard. It only would be allowed if your dereference a byte type, like "*reinterpret_cast<char*>( &... )".

Comment: @AntonF. I think I'm convinced. The reason I resisted the option of memcpy was because of perceived overhead but it turns out that the compiler "knows about memcpy" and optimizes it away. Even the overhead of using a function is optimized out https://blog.regehr.org/archives/959 and it generates exactly the same code as my original example https://godbolt.org/z/nVXagN .

Comment: @ppetraki: You're welcome. Now your edited answer is correct and with optimization it might be the fastest way to convert the value.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: This method "works" but according to some folks it relies on the compiler to allow it as technically it produces undefined behavior. So use at your own risk.**

And still another way is to use a union. Depending upon endianess, you will have to order your buffer correctly. See below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union u{ 
    unsigned char buffer[4]; 
    unsigned int x; 
} u; 



int main()
{

    u.buffer[0] = 0;
    u.buffer[1] = 2;
    u.buffer[2] = 0;
    u.buffer[3] = 0;


    printf("%d\n", u.x);

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in a comment, you can use union initialization as well. See below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union u{ 
    uint8_t buffer[4]; 
    uint32_t x; 
}; 

int main()
{
    union u u1 = {.buffer = {0,2,0,0} };
    printf("%d\n", u1.x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Union initialization would be a little more efficient. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: @ppetraki The standard doesn't allow this. You are only allowed to use the "active field". Only read from that field you wrote most recently!

Comment: @AntonF. Could you please cite a source? Because this works just fine.

Comment: It works on most compilers, but is not safe and not portable. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union section Member lifetime: "The lifetime of a union member begins when the member is made active. If another member was active previously, its lifetime ends." Think of optimization/register storage etc.

Comment: This code is *Undefined behavior*. The statement `u1.x` accesses to "ended-lifetime" member, as @AntonF. said.

Comment: @BiagioFesta Thanks for the information. I've always heard of using this technique and never knew it was technically undefined behavior.